# Multiple mysite hosts + fba

Tags: 2010, my-site, forms-authentication

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this. I need to create a mysite host for an FBA site in SP2010 (I'm already researching the FBA particulars parallel to this, but if anyone could give a hint to this too, it would be appreciated).

The "design" situation I'm trying to wrap myself around is that this mysite hosts needs to ONLY be for this one particular web application on the server, as there are other web apps already on here, with a mysite host. It might be a silly question, but can I simply create more mysite web applications on the same server, and restrict which web applications are able to use it?

And also, the reason for all of this is, that at a future point in time, I may need to relocate this entire web application + related mysite - is this a straight forward procedure? The web application itself I planned to simply create a complete backup of, and restore it on a different server - can I do the same thing with the mysite web application?

**UPDATE**

I created a second User Profile Service, configured it, and created a second mysite webapplication using claims, set up the FBA connection and provider, and now I can reach this second mysite host from my FBA site, however, I just get a sign in page, that repeats when I login (as in, I login, and come straight back to the login page) Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what happened. I triple checked everything, then rebooted the server again, and deleted all cookies in my browser, and then it worked. :)

Comment: So does this mean you got FBA working with a SharePoint MySite? I've had FBA working for a while now without any problems, but finding it difficult to integrate my users with a mysite so that they have profile pages, etc., and finding it even harder to find any help on the internet! So you created an extra web app, and site, then just linking to this from your original, uysing the same users DB, providers etc.? Any help on this would be great!?! Thanks,
Bav